# sum of (some) $p$-th roots of unity, $p$ prime

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $p$ be a prime and suppose $e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_p$ denote some $p$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, not necessarily distinct.

If
$$e_1 + e_2 + \cdots + e_p=0,$$
then, can we always conclude that all $e_i$'s are the distinct?

---

Note that for $p=2$ this is true, and so one may assume $p>2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime, you can indeed only get $0$ as a sum of $p$ such $p$-th roots of unity by taking the $p$ distinct roots once each.

I don't know how much field theory you have done, but here is an explanation of something much more general: Let $\omega \neq 1$ be a complex number satisfying $\omega^{p} = 1.$ Then the $p$-th roots of unity are $\{\omega^{i}: 0 \leq i \leq p-1 \}.$ Furthermore, the polynomial $x^{p}-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ factors as
$(x-1)( 1 + x + \ldots + x^{p-2}+x^{p-1}),$ and the second factor (which we now call $f(x)$) is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by Eisenstein's criterion. Note that $\omega$ is a root of $f(x).$.

This implies by general theory that $\{1,\omega,\omega^{2},\ldots,\omega^{p-3}, \omega^{p-2} \}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}.$ So every non-zero element which is expressible as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of these elements has a unique such expression. Since $-\omega^{p-1} = 1 + \omega+ \omega^{2}+ \ldots + \omega^{p-3} + \omega^{p-2}$ is the unique way to express $-\omega^{p-1}$ this way, we see that 
$0 = q(1 + \omega + \omega^{2} + \ldots + \omega^{p-1})$ is the only way to write $0$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $\{1,\omega,\omega^{2},\ldots,\omega^{p-1} \},$ where $q$ can be any rational number. Hence the only way to write $0$ as a sum of $p$ such $p$-th roots of unity is the case $q = 1.$

Comment: Thanks; simple, but I didn't thought with this perspective. Nice answer, and thanks for the transparent clarification.

Comment: I was writing my answer when ancientmathematician's answer appeared. That answer is correct, though written more tersely.

Comment: No offense, but this is the SAME proof as in the other answer with the difference being, that the other answer does it in a short and elegant way AND was given earlier. I cannot believe that the other answer has two downvotes, while this one is accepted. Of course the OP is free to choose the answer he wants to accept, but at least also upvote the other answer...

Comment: @Moos: No offence taken: I was writing my answer before I saw ancientmathematician's as I said above.

Comment: Yes, this is all fine. This was meant to be directed at the OP, who apparently still believes the other answer is wrong (See his edit of the question, where he says that 'unnecessary [..] answers' were posted).

Comment: @Moos:I think (s)he may have been referring to an earlier comment that someone made, which is now deleted. In any case, I have also pointed out above that the answer by ancientmathematician is correct.

Comment: You know, @GeoffRobinson, that terseness was always my way.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think adding an example would make it easier for people just get started...

Comment: He still has not apologized for accusing the other answer of being wrong and for accusing the answerer of not having read the question properly (he did so in a comment to that answer, that he now deleted). Seriously, he asks for help, then gets help, but does not appreciate it because he has no will to give the proof a second thought when he has not understood it at first. Then - after someone tells him that the answer is alright - he just deletes his comments and does not apologize for accusing the answer of being wrong. IMHO this is very bad behavior. No more answers for this guy from me...

Comment: @ancientmathematician: I might know that if I knew who you were. I didn't mean "terse" in any negative sense- I did think of using "compact" or "economical", but "terse" was  shorter and hence more efficient :)

Comment: @Geoff: the difference in answers was stressing *Eisenstein's criteria* (other answer) and *independence of $1,\omega,\cdots,\omega^{p-2}$* (in your answer); and in this sense, your answer quickly clarified answer to question. (Of course, this independence is consequence of E.C. (Eisenstein'ts criteria); but instead of E.C.  if one suggest to use the independence, the answer is more obvious than giving hint of E.C. ; the criteria is for *irreducibility* which has a consequence of something different phenomena - independence.)

Comment: I apologise to all especially OP for terseness of answer, and abruptness of comments. And you do know me, @GeoffRobinson, only you don't know that you do.

Comment: @ancientmathematician : I thought by the phrasing of your comment that you must know me, but I can not guess your identity- which is, I guess, the point of a pseudonym

Answer (score 5):

Let $p$ be prime and let $\zeta:=\exp\frac{2\pi}{p}$. Then the $p$-th rootsof unity are $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\dots,\zeta^{p-1}$.

Moreover, 
$$\sum_{0}^{p-1} a_i \zeta^{i}=0 \mbox{ for some } a_i\in\mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow a_i=c\mbox{ for all }.i$$ 
This is a consequence of the irreducibility of $X^{p-1}+\dots+X+1$, easily seen by Eisenstein.)

Comment: I am not, the $a_i$ allow for multiple appearances.

Comment: I think the question asked if $p$ many (not necessarily distinct) $p^{\operatorname{th}}$ root of unity sums up to zero, does it followed that they are distinct?

Comment: And my answer shows that the answer is "Yes".

Comment: @AlexVong He shows that the condition $\sum a_i=p$ (which is the hypothesis of the OP) implies all $a_i=1$. So he answered the question affirmatively.

Comment: @Beginner You are not thinking through the answer properly. It is 100% correct.

Comment: @MooS I see, thanks for explaining.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Sorry, I was *not following your argument* in beginning; the stress in your answer was on *Eisenstein's criteria*; but, as Geoff exlains, it is the *linear independence* of $1,\zeta,\cdots,\zeta^{p-2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which easily gives answetr to question. Sorry (I have voted up)!

Comment: @Moos: I agree your last comment; It is now clear, sorry for the confusion. (I have explained my confusion in a comment to Geoff's answer and the previous comment also).

Comment: @Beginner, see my apology above. But I think it's worth rethinking Eisenstein and other irreducibility tests: their purpose is to establish the linear independence of certain sets, and I should have realised not everyone thinks of them that way.

Comment: I agree (after 17 minutes after down vote, I realized correctness in your answer, and tried to upvote; it was not upvoting, but I edited a little, and up-voted - this is because, I "don't" follow psychologically voting/downvoting answers!)

Comment: I agree that it is irreducibility criteria playing role; but, I was thinking, if I post the above question in two classes as exercise, and give hint as "Eisenstein criteria" in one class, and "use independence of $1,\zeta,\cdots,\zeta^{p-2}$" in other class then the other class may solve quickly; they will *naturally think* how to prove this independency, the natural way comes is Eisenstein's criteria. But, directly juping to Eisensteins' criterial I don't find fruitful.

Comment: @Beginner: I wouldn't give them hints! Actually what I always wondered about when setting this  question was whether any of my students would come up with an intuitive geometric as opposed to algebraic answer -- an algebraic hint would steer them away from that sort of idea. I'd still like to see a geometric answer.